# How to get a tax refund for computer accessories purchased on a visit to USA?

Tags: usa, new-york-city, shopping, tax-refunds

I am about to buy two Mac accessories in the Apple Store in Manhattan which cost a total of $98 before tax.

I would like to get a refund for the tax before I get back to Europe.

My question is what should I ask from the cashier in the Apple Store, and what should I do in the Newark/JFK airport.

I found [a post on TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g60763-i5-k3036773-Tax_Refund_in_NYC-New_York_City_New_York.html), but it is a bit ambivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you could claim a Sales Tax Refund from New York State.  To do that you need to fill out [AU-11](http://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/st/au11_fill_in.pdf) form in which you can claim refund for goods you are taking out of state.  And mail it to the state.  Problem is that under NY law you likely won't qualify for a refund and on top of this they can only return NY State Portion which is 4%.  So if you want the hassle over $4 then by all means.

Comment: The form you linked for is for those exempt from sales tax, not tourists.

Comment: @littleadv The only thing that you may have to claim that this was not for the personal use but for business use outside the US.  And who says that it isn't.

Comment: So you suggest lying? Oh, why didn't you say so! Of course lying to get a tax refund is a way to go, ask Al Capone, worked well, for him!

Comment: @littleadv A visitor can purchase equipment that will be used for a business purpose outside the United States.  Why is that lying?

Comment: because that wouldn't be the truth? As you said, "who says that it isn't.".... A visitor can, but your answer suggests that any visitor will. What you're suggesting to do is illegal, but I'm not surprised at all at the amount of upvotes you've got as the people here are clueless on many issues.

Comment: Here's the instructions for AU-11. Read it carefully. http://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/st/au11i.pdf

Comment: Well the answer is still partially useful, is it not @littleadv?  For those who ARE getting it for business use, they can use it, and for those who aren't, DON'T USE IT.  Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @MarkMayo I would expect it to be explicitly told in the answer that this form is **only** for exempted entities/individuals. I'm afraid people who aren't familiar with the US and NY laws might read the answer as is, submit the form, and get into a lot of troubles.

Comment: @littleadv If you read the instructions the exemption you refer to is only for the entities registered with NY State Department of Taxes and Finance.  A foreign entity wouldn't be.  Secondly nowhere it suggests that the visitor will receive a refund it only says that a visitor "can" claim one and to do so he or she will have to show that he or she is eligible for it.  And **nowhere** does it state that you will receive one.

Comment: @Karlson yeah, that's my point. The form is for exempt entities. That's exactly why I said your answer is wrong.

Comment: @littleadv It's divided into sections: "Applicants not registered with the Department of Taxation and Finance" and "Applicants registered with the Department of Taxation and Finance" for those that are "registered" exemption is required.  A Foreigner or a Company from outside the United States would rarely be registered in the State of New York and don't have to claim that they are exempt from the payment of sales tax.  They can attempt to claim that the merchandise would be transported and used outside the state.

Comment: @Karlson, you keep arguing. Why? As if you're trying to convince me that lying to get a tax refund is something a normative person what do. Are you for real? Your answer is **wrong**. Plain and simple. Read the link I gave you. If you still don't understand why you're wrong - read it again. You won't become all of a sudden right by bluntly ignoring everything there and repeating your nonsense.

Answer (score 14):

To the best of my knowledge, New York State does not offer a refund of sales tax on purchases that are later taken outside the state or country.  Except for the North Dakota and Louisiana programs mentioned in the link you give, I have never heard of such refunds existing anywhere in the U.S.

I think you just have to pay it.

Comment: The North Dakota program is still in place, but only applies to Canadian residents.  Washington has a plan to refund sales tax as well, but you must live in a jurisdiction with a lower tax rate, e.g. Alberta.