# Reclaiming tax from US purchases

Tags: usa, shopping, tax-refunds

I'm traveling in the US (originally from Australia) and buying a few things like shoes etc and a friend said I might be able to claim the tax back on my purchases. Does anyone know if this is right and if so how do I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a tax refund for purchase Apple Mac Accessories?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6767/how-to-get-a-tax-refund-for-purchase-apple-mac-accessories)

Comment: It's a state by state thing.  There is no federal VAT tax that you have in most other countries.

Comment: Perhaps merging of these two questions. Otherwise, campo, please include which state your question is about.

Comment: California mostly I'd like to claim tax back on. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Alternatively, go to Oregon and you don't have to pay sales tax at all! It's nice being able to buy something in the US and know the amount you see on the shelf is the amount you'll be paying at the checkout :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no state tax refunds to tourists in any of the US States except for Louisiana and Texas. In Louisiana there's a similar to the European "Tax Fee" program in effect, and tax refund can be done in the New Orleans airport or by mail for qualified purchases.

Texas also has a [similar program](http://www.taxfreetexas.com/) available at participating stores.

Comment: Even the Louisiana program is only if you are catching an international flight directly out of Louisiana.  ie, not connecting at another airport in the US.  Last I looked there weren't too many flights from Louisiana to Australia :)

Comment: @Doc you can get refund by mail, though.

Comment: @littleadv Please take a look at the question I linked.  There is such thing as Sales Tax Refund it is done differently then in countries with VAT.

Comment: @Karlson your answer there is wrong.

Comment: @littleadv Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Karlson I elaborated there. You said New York refunds sales tax to visitors. New York doesn't.

Comment: and Texas http://www.taxfreetexas.com/