# Tax refund flying out of California?

Tags: air-travel, usa, california, tax-refunds

I have an international flight from Los Angeles airport (LAX). I bought a laptop and tablet in the USA, and I wanted to know if I can get a tax refund. I know that the US doesn't have VAT, but I don't know about sales tax. Is it possible to get a refund?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/6769/1362

Comment: While there is no way to get the sales tax back at the airport, it *should* be possible to save the tax at the time of the initial purchase *by having the store ship the goods to Australia right then*. Generally speaking, sales tax (if any) is due in the state where the buyer lives.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Page 5, section 8 of this California Board of Equalization [newsletter](http://www.boe.ca.gov/news/pdf/sep99fnl.pdf) has the answer:

> 8. Items Sold to Residents of a Foreign Country or Another State
>
> We have received complaints from foreign buyers that they were
>   incorrectly advised by retailers that they could receive a refund of
>   the sales tax on items they purchased and picked up in California.
>   They were told they could do this by presenting their receipts at the
>   airport. Although many countries have such a provision for foreign
>   travelers, California does not.
>
> Nor does California have this provision for residents of other states.
>   Consequently, if foreign tourists ask about a refund of tax paid on
>   purchases, you should inform them that tax applies to merchandise
>   delivered in California regardless of its ultimate destination.